# Python Tkinter refreshing label

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import time
import keyboard
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter import Image
import os

miners = 0
stone = 0
test = 0
czas = time.sleep(8)
automine = 0 

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Let s Mine!")

bigfont = Font(family='Franklin Gothic Medium', size=42,weight='bold',slant='roman',underline=0,overstrike=0)

root.geometry("720x1080")
root.configure(bg="#add8e6")

l = Label(root, text = "LET'S MINE!",font=bigfont,bg="#add8e6", fg= "#ededd0")
l.grid(row=0,column=0)
l.pack()
w = Canvas(root, width=720, height=200)
photo = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\RUDY RYC\Desktop\Adam\projekty\gra\stone.png")
w.configure(bg='#90EE90')
def mine():
    global stone
    time.sleep(5)
    stone += stone
    stone1.config(text=stone)
    
x = Button(root,  text="MINE STONE!", image=photo, command=mine)
stone1 = Label(root, text = stone, height=20, bg="#add8e6")
stone1.pack(side=tk.TOP)

x.configure(font=bigfont, height=150, width=150)

x.pack()

w.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop

while True:
    answer = input("Co chcesz zrobić?")
    if answer == "mine" and test == 0:
        test = 1

    if test == 1:
        test = 0
        print("Mining stone...")
        time.sleep(5)
        stone = stone+1

    if answer == "gornik" and stone >= 2:
        print('Poczekaj 4 Sekundy')
        time.sleep(4)
        print("Pomyslnie zdobyto Gornika")
        miners = miners+1
        stone = stone-2
        print("Masz teraz" + " " + str(miners) + " " + "Górników")
    elif stone < 2 and answer == "gornik":
        print('Nie masz wystarczajacej ilosci Kamienia')

    if miners >= 2 and answer == "automine":
        automine = 1 
        print('You turned on automatic mining')
```

I am trying to make something like a basic game about mining and other stuff in Minecraft universe. The thing is I am trying to refresh the label with the counter (I mean the `w`) every time the mine thing happens but it doesn't work. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I've tried refreshing `root`, and `w.update`.

Comment: Two fundamental issues with your code `root.mainloop` should be `root.mainloop()` and everything after mainloop won't be executed until the GUI is closed. While loops and tkinter don't mix. You should use the tkinter `.after` method to schedule a function to be called after a specified delay.

Answer (score 0):

Next to the problem that you have two different programs, here, and only a question regarding the first one, your `mine()` function is a little off.

- You add stone to stone, which will always be 0, as stone is initially 0
- You don't update the label
- You assign an integer to the text argument (might work but it's not nice)
- You sleep before doing anything, giving the impression that it has frozen

Your function should look like this:

```
def mine():
    global stone
    stone += 1
    stone1.config(text=str(stone))
    stone1.update()
    time.sleep(5)
```

With this function, it works just fine.

(P.S: you confused width and height in the toplevel geometry. Make it: `root.geometry("1080x720")`